# W state Entanglement Breaks During $X$-Basis Measurement

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-circuit, w-state

I'm encountering a problem in my Qiskit simulation involving W-state entanglement. The issue arises when attempting to measure all three qubits in the $X$ measurement basis. Surprisingly, the entanglement breaks, and this behavior is consistent even when running the code on a real quantum device.

```python
import numpy as np

# Define a F_gate
def F_gate(circ, q, i, j, n, k):
    theta = np.arccos(np.sqrt(1/(n-k+1)))
    circ.ry(-theta, q[j])
    circ.cz(q[i], q[j])
    circ.ry(theta, q[j])
    circ.barrier(q[i])

# Define the cxrv gate which uses reverse CNOT instead of CNOT
def cxrv(circ, q, i, j):
    circ.h(q[i])
    circ.h(q[j])
    circ.cx(q[j], q[i])
    circ.h(q[i])
    circ.h(q[j])
    circ.barrier(q[i], q[j])

# Define the flag_qx2 variable
flag_qx2 = True  # Set it to True or False based on your requirements

singlet = QuantumCircuit(qr, cr)

singlet.x(qr[2])  # start is |100>
F_gate(singlet, qr, 2, 1, 3, 1)  # Applying F12
F_gate(singlet, qr, 1, 0, 3, 2)  # Applying F23

if flag_qx2:  # option ibmqx2
    singlet.cx(qr[1], qr[2])  # cNOT 21
    singlet.cx(qr[0], qr[1])  # cNOT 32
else:  # option ibmqx4
    cxrv(singlet, qr, 1, 2)
    cxrv(singlet, qr, 0, 1)

for i in range(3):
    singlet.h(qr[i])  # Apply Hadamard gate for X basis
    singlet.measure(qr[i], cr[i])
```

The problem seems to be related to measuring in the $X$ basis. When measuring in the Z basis, the W state is correctly obtained which is $|001\rangle, |010\rangle, |001\rangle$. However, measuring in the $X$ basis results in the breakdown of entanglement and giving significant state of $|000\rangle , |011\rangle$ etc.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and preserve entanglement during $X$-basis measurements.

I attempted to simulate a quantum circuit using Qiskit, specifically focusing on a W-state entanglement scenario. The goal was to measure all three qubits in the $X$ measurement basis. I expected that the entanglement would be preserved, as observed when measuring in the $Z$ basis. However, the actual result was a breakdown of entanglement during $X$-basis measurements. This behavior persisted when running the code on both the simulator and a real quantum device. I am seeking insights or suggestions on how to address this issue and maintain entanglement in the $X$-basis measurements.

NOTE: I know W state is not a singlet state rather it can be say as Triplet state.

Comment: What do you mean by breakdown of entanglement? By definition, if you measure all three qubits, you will get some unentangled states with some probabilities. This is the same for Z basis measurements, as $\left|001\right>$, $\left|010\right>$ and $\left|100\right>$ are not entangled.
The result for X basis will be different and it not be so obvious as in Z basis, but still we can express $W$ as the superposition of all possible measurement results. Just expand each $\left|0\right>$ and $\left|1\right>$ in the definition of $W$ in the X basis

Comment: Sorry for the misuse of the term breakdown of entanglement. In the X basis, when we measure the three qubits together, we still see some entanglement, but it appears as probabilities and connections between results. However, for my secret key generation, I want to get specific W states: |001⟩, |010⟩, |100⟩. To do this, I need to measure the W state in the same measurement basis each time, similar to the E91 protocol. But it's not happening. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what the question is. If you want one of the states $\left|001\right>$, $\left|010\right>$, $\left|100\right>$, then prepare a $W$ state and measure it in Z basis, you'll get these states with equal probabilities. If you try to do something else, you will not get this result. You do not need to involve X basis for this at all. If you need something else, then please write what do you need to find or construct, what are you doing and where do you think it goes wrong.

Comment: [link]https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10773-020-04653-4 
Please look at steps four five and six on the paper.

Comment: Step 6 in the paper only applies to Z basis. This is because in step 5 Charlie specifically chooses one of $W$ states where all parties measured in Z basis.

Comment: Please look at steps 4 and 5 again. The basis is measured in X basis by all parties or Z by all parties. In the paper, they apply 2 measurement bases.

Comment: You misunderstand (admittedly, the language in the paper is not the best). In step 4, for each of many states, Alice, Bob and Charlie choose independently a random basis (X or Z), measure in this basis and record the seqeunce of all bases chosen and the sequence of all measurement results. In step 5, Alice and Bob send the seqeunces of bases they chose to Charlie, and Charlie chooses one of the $W$ states that was measured in Z basis by all three parties.

Comment: This is slightly more clear in the followup paper https://doi.org/10.1007/s10773-023-05396-8

Comment: But doesn't it make it vulnerable to eavesdropping? I am trying to make a protocol which will be similar to e91 with W state

Comment: The quantum channel is protected from eavesdropping by inserting random $\left|0\right>$, $\left|1\right>$, $\left|+\right>$, $\left|-\right>$ states between $W$, so if the eavesdropper measures states, it will be detected at step 3. If the eavesdropper listens to the classical communication when the bases are transferred, he will not have any information about the measurement results. Depending on the attack model, I think the protocol still requires a protected channel between Charlie and Alice on step 5, otherwise eavesdroppers will know which bits Alice queries.